# Acessing ARP table of Host from Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, arp

How can I access the host ARP records from within a Docker container?

I tried to mount a volume (in a docker-compose file) `/proc/net/arp:/proc/net/arp` but  found out that I can't make any volume with `/proc`. Then I tried to mount it elsewhere like `/proc/net/arp:/root/arp`, but then if I `cat /root/arp`, from within the container, the table comes out empty.

```
docker run -v /proc/net/arp:/root/arp alpine cat /root/arp     <-- returns empty table
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be good if you add privileged mode and make sure you're in host networking mode. This worked for me:

```
>$ docker run --net host --privileged -v /proc/net/arp:/host/arp alpine cat /host/arp
```

Comment: On MacOS with Docker Desktop, it only returns the interfaces attached to the docker subnet. `192.168.65.7` and `192.168.65.1`