# Acessing ARP table of Host from Docker container on MacOS

Tags: docker

This is basically the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141091/acessing-arp-table-of-host-from-docker-container), except on a Mac, setting network to `host` has no effect whatsoever.

I'm trying to give a Docker container, running on MacOS, access to its host ARP table. My `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
services:
  homeassistant:
    container_name: home-assistant
    image: homeassistant/home-assistant
    environment:
      # This is the required way to set a timezone on macOS and differs from the Linux compose file
      - TZ=XX/XXXX
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
    restart: unless-stopped
    privileged: true
    ports:
      # Also required for macOS since the network directive in docker-compose does not work
      - "8123:8123"

# Add this or docker-compose will complain that it did not find the key for locally mapped volume
volumes:
  config:
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you actually can't do this, because Docker on MacOS runs inside a hidden Linux VM (the same reason host networking doesn't work).  Low-level network management tools aren't something you'd usually want to run inside a container in any case.

Comment: @DavidMaze - what if I want to advertise `homeassistant` to the host's network so that HomeKit recognizes it? this requires mDNS/Bonjour.